changing xfce standard windows symbols ^_□X
At the upper right of almost all windows XFCE presents are four symbols,  ^ _ ﻿□ X.  _ is for minimize, X is for close etc.  The box symbol can be one of two, a toggle, between full screen and window.  How can I change that box symbol to be perhaps a box for 'in window, want full screen' and a plus + for 'in full screen want a window'.  Maybe I've got the box and + backward.  The key thing here is that there is currently very little difference between the box for full screen and the box for window.  I am now running Xubuntu 24.04
